# WordPress is not automatically wrapping root level shortcode content in paragraph tags

Tags: wordpress, filter, shortcode

When a shortcode is used inside a block of text, it displays as expected.  However, when used on a line by itself, the content somehow bypasses WordPress' automatic paragraph wrapping, and is therefore styled differently.

Consider the following setup:

```
/**
 * A shortcode that just returns the content its wrapping
 */
function do_echo_shortcode( $args, $content ): string {
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode( 'echo', 'do_echo_shortcode' );
```

Creating a new post on the site, I enter the following content in the WYSIWYG editor:

> This is a paragraph
>
> [echo]This is also one[/echo]
>
> But here's an [echo]echo[/echo] inside a paragraph!

When viewing the page, the following HTML is generated:

```
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
This is also one
<p>But here’s an echo inside a paragraph!</p>
```

As a result, the second line is styled differently as it is not automatically wrapped in a paragraph tag.

Altering the do_echo_shortcode function above, I can apply a filter to the content:

`return apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );`

This resolves the issue, but introduces a new one, as it breaks up the 3rd line.  The resulting HTML is as follows:

```
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p>This is also one</p>

<p>But here’s an </p><p>echo</p>
inside a paragraph!<p></p>
```

By creating a debugging function and attaching it to 'the_content' filter hook, we can see the content as it's being processed:

```
function debug_the_content( $content ) {
    // print the content to the log, or attach a debugger here to see the content
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'debug_the_content' );
```

This gives me some interesting insight, but I'm still not able to solve the problem.  For the first example above (without manually filtering the content in the shortcode function), we see the following values for '$content':

1. `<p>This is a paragraph</p>\n <p>But here&#8217;s an  inside a paragraph!</p>\n`
2. `This is also one`
3. `echo`
4. `<p>This is a paragraph</p>\nThis is also one\n<p>But here&#8217;s an echo inside a paragraph!</p>\n`

Finally, to wrap this whole thing up, here's the output that I'm hoping to achieve:

```
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p>This is also one</p>
<p>But here’s an echo inside a paragraph!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the simplest option is just to wrap your echo shortcode in `<p>` tags in your `WYSIWYG` editor...

```txt
This is a paragraph

<p>[echo]This is also one[/echo]</p>

But here's an [echo]echo[/echo] inside a paragraph!
```

Or you can add a custom tag attribute to your echo shortcode like this...

```txt
This is a paragraph

[echo tag="p"]This is also one[/echo]

But here's an [echo]echo[/echo] inside a paragraph!
```

Using this `add_shortcode` function, see comments in php code below...

```php
/**
 * shortcode that just returns the content value
 * excepts 'tag' attribute to define html tag to wrap content inside
 */
function do_echo_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {

    // check if the 'tag' attribute exists and is not empty
    if (isset($atts['tag']) && !empty($atts['tag'])) {
    
        // extract and sanitize the 'tag' attribute
        $tag = sanitize_html_class($atts['tag']);

        // wrap the content in the specified html 'tag'
        $output = '<' . $tag . '>' . do_shortcode($content) . '</' . $tag . '>';

    } else {
    
        // if html 'tag' wrapper attribute is not defined, return the content as is
        $output = do_shortcode($content);

    }

    // return final shortcode output
    return $output;
    
}

// add do echo shortcode
add_shortcode('echo', 'do_echo_shortcode');
```

Hope this helps